# Как хранить в Android приложении длинный список слов?

Tags: java, android, хранение-данных

При простом их перечислении в коде выдаёт ошибку code too large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храни в файле списком. Добавь его в assets папку и загружай через AssetManager.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать

Comment: А как мне потом из этого списка сделать массив?

Comment: как насчет базы данных

Comment: @КубаркоДмитрий Сохрани слова, разделённые `\n` (новой строкой), Получи `InputStream` из `AssetManager`, оберни в `Scanner` и читай его по строчкам через `.nextLine()`. Получил - пихай в массив.

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Да тут способов очень много, зависит от  дальнеёших действий над ними. Основные из них: База данных, хранить в файле, в преферансах ну и если это не изменяемые данные, то в строковых ресурсах, в , если данные не будут меняться, то последний вариант для вас идеальный, делаем так:

```
<string-array name="my_string_array">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
</string-array>
```

Получаем вот так:

```
String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);
```